# Can't Pass Values to Javascript Modal (Not Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, modal-dialog

I'm having issues with trying to pass a value to a non-bootstrap modal. **The way my current php loop is written**, ***I understand* that I can only use my modal to edit the last row in my SQL table**. However when my modal div was inside the loop, I would only able to alter the first row of the SQL table. How could I modify my scripts to accept the value from the button which loads my modal?

PHP:

```
<?php
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($select)) 
{
$idtemp=$row['id'];
<button id="edit_form<?php echo $idtemp;?>"  data-target="#id02" data-id="<?php echo $idtemp;?>"  onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='block'">Edit</button>
 <?php
}
?>
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="id02" class="modal">
  <span onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" 
class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
  <!-- Modal Content -->
  <form class="modal-content animate" id="editForm" action="modify_records.php" method="post">

    <div class="container">
       <h3>Edit an Existing Project</h3>

          <label for="Project_Name" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Project Name:</label>
          <input type="text" name="Project_Name" id="Project_Name_Edit" placeholder="Project Name">
          <br><br>
          <label for="Partners" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Partners:</label>
          <?php
          echo $partnersmenu;
          ?>
         <br><br>
          <label for="blank" class="ui-hidden-accessible">. </label>
             <br><br>

          <br><br>
  <input type="button" id="edit_button" class="edit_button" value="Submit"  onclick="edit_row(<?php echo $idtemp;?>);">
          <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
    </div> 
    <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function edit_row(id){
initialize variables
send ajax data to modify_records.php
...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:Solution with hidden-field:

First give a class to your buttons in your loop

```
<?php
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($select)) 
{
$idtemp=$row['id'];
<button class="openModal" id="edit_form<?php echo $idtemp;?>"  data-target="#id02" data-id="<?php echo $idtemp;?>"  onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='block'">Edit</button>
 <?php
}
?>
```

Than put a hidden-field in your modal

```
<div id="id02" class="modal">
  <span onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" 
class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
  <!-- Modal Content -->
  <form class="modal-content animate" id="editForm" action="modify_records.php" method="post">

    <div class="container">
       <h3>Edit an Existing Project</h3>

          <label for="Project_Name" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Project Name:</label>
          <input type="text" name="Project_Name" id="Project_Name_Edit" placeholder="Project Name">
          <br><br>
          <label for="Partners" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Partners:</label>
          <?php
          echo $partnersmenu;
          ?>
         <br><br>
          <label for="blank" class="ui-hidden-accessible">. </label>
             <br><br>

          <br><br>
  <input type="button" id="edit_button" class="edit_button" value="Submit"  onclick="edit_row(<?php echo $idtemp;?>);">
  <input type="hidden" id="hidden_temp_id">
          <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
    </div> 
    <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Than create in your js-file  eventlistener to your buttons

```
var openModalButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("openModal");
for (var i = 0; i < openModalButtons.length; i++) {
    openModalButtons[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
}

var myFunction = function() {
    var idtemp = this.getAttribute("data-id");
    document.getElementById('hidden_temp_id').value = idtemp;
};
```

Comment: Previously, the div for the modal was within the php loop so that $idtemp  was changing with the loop, however the loop would reset the value once the modal was open. Please keep in mind that I've tried using hidden inputs as well, I would get the same result.

Comment: You can do it with a hidden-field. How do you try it? Put just one hidden-field in your modal and when you click one of your buttons of your loop, than replace your hidden-fields value with your data-id from your button.

Comment: That sounds like an interesting solution, how can I replace the hidden field value with the data-id though?

Comment: Unfortunately, its not picking up the values you've assigned to the hidden input. :( I appreciate your help though. Just so we're clear, I put your javascript before my edit_row function.

Comment: Of course, you have to modify your javascript function edit_row(id) too.
Instead of passing an id, just call it without a parameter. And in your function you grab the value from your hidden-field, because your id is in there.

Comment: Ah, that should've been obvious. I apologize. However, when I went looking for the updated value for the hidden-field, I don't see the data-id value. I'm going through and debugging your javascript and it seems like the update never takes place.

Comment: This code does update the the hidden field...but only updates the first value. `var openModalButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("openModal");
for (var i = 0; i < openModalButtons.length; i++) {
    openModalButtons[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction(), false);
 } 
function myFunction(){
    var idtemp = $(openModalButtons).data("id");
    document.getElementById('hidden_temp_id').value = idtemp;
};`

Comment: I get the feeling its something simple I'm missing by a mile. Anyone?

Comment: Replace $(openModalButtons).data("id"); with $(this).data("id");
or if it doesnt work try this, $(this).attr("data-id");

Comment: I actually tried using those two methods, neither of them works.

Comment: Maybe you can simulate your problem with jsfiddle so we can get a better view of your code. Otherwise its hard to tell whats going wrong. Or someone else can help you better than me.

Comment: The problem with jsfiddle is that it doesn't simulate the problem with the dynamic ids from the php.

Comment: Your php is not the problem. Just put manually a few buttons with ids. Everything else is html and javascript.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/z6woaah6/17/
Here, now your hidden-field changes everytime you click on your edit button. The Problem was the eventListener. I just edited your javascript-file and include jquery, but you using it anyway.

You included jquery in your html, right? Because you was using it in your javascript. I add it in your fiddle for you.